# Extracting vector graphics (lines and points) with pdfclown

Tags: vector, graphics, pdfclown

I want to extract vector graphics (lines and points) out of a pdf with pdfclown. I have tried to wrap my head around the graphics sample but i cannot figure out how the object model works for this. Please can anyone explain the relationships?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not asking a specific question about existing code. It's just asking for people to explain a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: till PDF Clown 0.1 series, high-level path modelling was not implemented (it would have been derived from [ContentScanner.GraphicsWrapper](http://clown.sourceforge.net/0.1/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/ContentScanner.GraphicsObjectWrapper.html)).

*Next release* ([0.2 series](http://pdfclown.org/), due next month) *will support the high-level representation of all the graphics contents, including path objects* (PathElement), through the new [ContentModeller](http://pdfclown.org/2014/09/12/waiting-for-pdf-clown-0-2-0-release/#ContentModeller). Here is an example:

```
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.elements.ContentModeller;
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.elements.GraphicsElement;
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.elements.PathElement;
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.Path;

import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;

for(GraphicsElement<?> element : ContentModeller.model(page, Path.class))
{
  PathElement pathElement = (PathElement)element;
  List<ContentMarker> markers = pathElement.getMarkers();
  pathElement.getBox();
  GeneralPath getPath = pathElement.getPath();
  pathElement.isFilled();
  pathElement.isStroked();
}
```

In the meantime, you can extract the low-level representation of the vector graphics iterating the content stream through [ContentScanner](http://clown.sourceforge.net/0.1/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/ContentScanner.html) as suggested in ContentScanningSample (available in the downloadable distribution), looking for path-related operations ([BeginSubpath](http://clown.sourceforge.net/0.1/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/objects/BeginSubpath.html), [DrawLine](http://clown.sourceforge.net/0.1/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/objects/DrawLine.html), [DrawRectangle](http://clown.sourceforge.net/0.1/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/objects/DrawRectangle.html), [DrawCurve](http://clown.sourceforge.net/0.1/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/objects/DrawCurve.html), ...).

Comment: Thank you. Very constructive answer. Im waiting like a child on christmas for the new release!

Comment: Stefano, the 0.2 series has not been released yet but you apparently had already written quite a lot of code and implemented quite a lot of functionality for it back in 2015. Would you consider publishing it even if it is not completely polished?