# Detecting Headers and Borders in PDF Tables using PDF Clown

Tags: pdf, pdfclown

I am using PDF Clown's TextInfoExtractionSample to extract a PDF table into Excel and I was able to do it except merged cells. In the below code, for object, "content" I see the scanned content as text, XObject, ContainerObject but nothing for borders. Anyone know what object represents borders in PDF table OR how to detect if a text is a header of the table?

```
   private void Extract(ContentScanner level, PrimitiveComposer composer)
   {
      if(level == null)
        return;
      while(level.MoveNext())
      {
        ContentObject content = level.Current;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I am using PDF Clown's `TextInfoExtractionSample`...
>
> In the below code, for object, "content" I see the scanned content as text, XObject, ContainerObject but nothing for borders.
>
> ```
> while(level.MoveNext())
> {
>     ContentObject content = level.Current;
> }
> ```

### A) Visit all content

In your loop code you removed very important blocks from the original example,

```
    if(content is XObject)
    {
        // Scan the external level!
        Extract(((XObject)content).GetScanner(level), composer);
    }
```

and

```
    if(content is ContainerObject)
    {
        // Scan the inner level!
        Extract(level.ChildLevel, composer);
    }
```

These blocks make the sample *recurse* into complex objects (the *XObject, ContainerObject* you mention) which in turn contain their own simple content.

### B) Inspect all content

> Anyone know what object represents borders in PDF table

Unfortunately there is nothing like a *border attribute* in PDF content. Instead, borders are independent objects, usually vector graphics, either lines or very thin rectangles.

Thus, while scanning the page content (recursively, as indicated in **A**) you will have to look for `Path` instances (namespace `org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects`) containing

- *moveTo* **m**, *lineTo* **l**, and *stroke* **S** operations or
- *rectangle* **re** and *fill* **f** operations.

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30641099/1729265) may help)

When you come across such lines, you will have to *interpret* them. These lines may be borders, but they may also be used as underlines, page decorations, ...

If the PDF happens to be tagged, things may be a bit easier insofar as you have to interpret less. Instead you can read the tagging information which may tell you where a cell starts and ends, so you do not need to interpret graphical lines. Unfortunately still less PDFs are tagged than not.

> OR how to detect if a text is a header of the table?

Just as above, unless you happen to inspect a tagged PDF, there is nothing immediately telling you some text is a table header. You have to interpret again. Is that text outside of lines you determined to form a table? Is it inside at the top? Or just anywhere inside? Is it drawn in a specific font? Or larger? Different color? Etc.